# Is it possible to evaluate the following limit involving a fibonacci dirichlet series?

Tags: analysis, limits

Consider the function $$ \psi(x) =  5^{\frac{x}{2} } \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-x}{k} \frac{1}{ \phi^{x+2k} + (-1)^{k+1} } \quad .$$

Is it possible to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to -1} \psi(x)$ ? I thought the correct answer is $$ \lim_{x \to -1} \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \Big{(} \frac{1}{\phi^{-1} -1} + \frac{1}{\phi + 1} \Big{)} = -1 \quad ,   $$ because we only have the $k=0$ and $k=1$ terms that are non-zero. I "know" the terms where $k >1$ are zero because of [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+n+ncr+k+if++k+%3E+n+). However, I don't *really* understand it and I don't know how to show it.

Furthermore, how can we prove the limit exists? And how do we show it converges to $-1$ (if it does at all) ? Or does it perhaps converge to some other value?

Comment: Can you define $\phi$?

Comment: $\psi(-1)=-1.2286493229640712255452132025425287040\ldots$

Comment: @drawnonward $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $.

Comment: @Lucian Really? How do you know this? Are you sure we are talking about the same function $\psi$ here?

Comment: @maxy: Sorry! I replaced $-x$ with $-1$ instead of $-(-1)=+1$. In general, $\displaystyle{n\choose k}=0$ if *n* and *k* are integers, and $n<k$. This is due to the fact that the factorials of negative integers are $\pm\infty$.